# R plotly - showlegend = FALSE does not work

Tags: r, plotly

Why does `showlegend = FALSE` not suppress the legend in this simplified R code generating a plotly scatterplot? Thanks for any assistance.

```
plot_ly(x =  ~  1:5,  y =  ~ 1:5, type="scatter",mode="markers",
 color =  1:5,
 showlegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `showlegend` parameter in `plot_ly` only refers to factor labels. e.g.

```
plot_ly(x =  ~  1:5,  y =  ~ 1:5, type="scatter",mode="markers",
    color =  as.factor(1:5))
```

[image]

```
plot_ly(x =  ~  1:5,  y =  ~ 1:5, type="scatter",mode="markers",
    color =  as.factor(1:5), showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Unfortunately `showscale` isn't implemented for scatter plots, so you need to use the less elegant `hide_colorbar()` function for color scales:

```
plot_ly(x =  ~  1:5,  y =  ~ 1:5, type="scatter",mode="markers",
        color =  1:5) %>% hide_colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That sure was a quick answer!

Comment: My pleasure :) If you consider it a full answer you should use the check mark to mark it as "answered"